# Count frequency of specific words in a dataset

Tags: r, text-mining, word-frequency

I dont have experience with text classification, so I'm not sure how to logically solve this. I have little R knowledge, so would prefer to solve it in R.

I have a 50000 * 32 data set. Of these, 7 columns contain text data like description, function, names etc. I am looking to classify each row into 6 different types if any words from a specific pre-defined list is available. I need the count of these pre-definied words occurring so that I can rule out accidental occurrences.

pre-definied list: day, today, night

+----------------------+---------------------------+-------+
|         col1         |           col2            | count |
+----------------------+---------------------------+-------+
| this is a sunny day  | the weather is good today |     2 |
| it is a rainy night  | the day is cloudy         |     2 |
| it is thursday today | have a good day           |     3 |
+----------------------+---------------------------+-------+

Comment: Chapter 1 might be of interest to you: https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html

Comment: If you can please share your data, I can replicate the below example using it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a way to find word frequency, using the `tm` package in R:

```
library(tm)
data("crude") #inbuild dataset in tm package, here you can use your text file
myTdm <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(crude))
FreqMat <- data.frame(ST = rownames(myTdm), 
                      Freq = rowSums(myTdm), 
                      row.names = NULL)
```

output

```
                    ST Freq
1                "(it)    1
2              "demand    1
3           "expansion    1
4                 "for    1
5              "growth    1
6                  "if    1
7                  "is    2
8                 "may    1
9                "none    2
10               "opec    2
11             "opec's    1
12                "our    1
13                "the    3
14              "there    1
15               "they    1
16               "this    4
17                 "we    2
18               "will    1
19               (bpd)    3
20              (bpd).    1
21               (gcc)    1
22           (northern    1
23               (oil)    1
24              (opec)    2
25              (uae),    1
26                 ...    2
27                 1.1    1
28                1.11    1
29                1.15    1
30                 1.2    3
31                1.50    4
32                 1.9    1
33                 1/8    1
34                10.8    1
35             100,000    1
36                 12.    1
37              12.217    1
38               12.32    1
39           13-member    1
40           13-nation    3
41               13.81    1
42               15-18    2
43                15.6    1
44                15.8    6
45               16.00    1
46               16.35    1
47               16.50    1
48               16.67    1
49               16.85    1
50                 168    1
51               17.52    1
52             180,000    1
53                 19.    1
54                1985    1
55               1985.    2
56             1985/86    2
57            1985/86.    1
58                1986    1
59               1986,    2
60             1986/87    2
61                1987    3
62             1987/88    3
63                 2.2    1
64                 2.5    1
65               2.766    1
66             200,000    1
67            200-foot    1
68                20s,    2
69               22.26    1
70             24-hour    1
71                 26.    1
72             285,000    2
73                 3.5    1
74                 3.6    1
75           3.7495/98    1
76           3.7500/03    1
77                 3.8    1
78                3/8,    1
79                 300    1
80                 4.0    1
81               4.133    1
82               5-3/4    1
83               5.472    1
84                 500    2
85              6-1/4,    1
86              6-5/8,    1
87               6-7/8    1
88               6.745    1
89              7-1/8,    1
90              7-3/8,    1
91                7.25    2
92                 7.3    1
93                 750    2
94                 9.7    1
95             948,000    2
96               <chv>    1
97              <mob>,    1
98                <tx>    1
99              <xon>,    1
100         abdul-aziz    5
101            ability    5
102           ability,    1
103               able    1
104              about   12
105              above    8
106            abroad,    1
107             accept    1
108             accord    6
109            accord,    1
110            accord.    1
111          according    4
112             across    1
113           activity    1
114          activity.    1
115                add    1
116              added    1
117             added.    3
118            address    3
119          addressed    1
120          adherence    1
121           adhering    2
122          advantage    1
123           advisers    1
124              after    8
125            again,"    1
126            against    3
127             agency    5
128             agreed    3
129          agreement    5
130         agreement.    1
131       agricultural    1
132      agriculture,"    1
133       agriculture.    1
134            aground    1
135         al-khalifa    3
136           al-qabas    3
137           al-sabah    2
138          al-sabah,    1
139           al-thani    1
140                ali    6
....
```

Comment: I dont want to find the most frequent words, but rather the frequency of some words in each row